# what is the meaning of lobule?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

When I communicate with my foreign client. I heard the following sentence. Can anybody explain what does he mean.

```
I'm lobule until tonight.
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: I think your client is actually saying ***available***

Comment: @Jim You mean he is not available until tonight

Comment: I don’t know what he meant really.  But If I am right about *available* I would guess that because he *didn’t* use the word *not* that he is available now but will become unavailable (presumably due to some other engagement) this evening.  Bottom line: better catch him now while you still can.

Answer (score 2):

By definition (Google) "lobule" means:

> a small lobe

I very much doubt the client meant *'I am a small lobe until tonight.'*, so my best guess would be, as Jim suggested, "available".